# Structured streaming output - compacting with OPTIMIZE without breaking outgoing read stream order guarantees

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks, delta-lake

I have an incoming "append only" stream of updates from kafka using structured streaming. writing using `foreachBatch` and inside it:

```
parsedDf \
    .select("parsedId", "ingestionDate","parsedValue.after", "parsedValue.patch", "parsedValue.op", "parsedvalue.ts_ms",  'partition', 'offset') \
    .write \
    .format("delta") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
    .save(f"/mnt/defaultDatalake/{append_table_name}")
```

Later, in a downstream job, I have a `readStream` reading the files creating there.

The problem - these jobs create tons of files because the topic isn't very full. While the downstream jobs are good with that (reading from the end of the stream) I also need to query this data directly (the append table), but then queries are very long because of the high number of files involved.

Naturally I've tried to use `OPTIMIZE` on this storage, but then it seems to break the order guarantees of the readStream using those files.

So what I need - a way to roll in small files to bigger files (let's say - older then a week) without breaking strict order guarantees for downstream consumers (even if it needs to reread the data from an earlier period)

Spark 3. Running in databricks 7.5

Comment: 1. because I process the stream, serialize from avro etc. 
2. I was told by databricks support Order is guaranteed with the readStream, , I do need to keep the data partitioning correctly so I won't lose order inside

Comment: I think the order is lost because Optimize is run with Z-order, is it? Can you please share the optimize command? You may want to just Optimize while stream processing is happening and 'Optimize with Z-order' when there is a down time.

Comment: No optimize with Z-order, just plain old optimize

Comment: Maybe the following solution will be simple: Introduce some buffering layer, such as Kinesis Firehose. You will end up with bigger files. I know this is not what you were asking specifically about, but it should be one solution. 
In addition, are you sure about " it seems to break the order guarantees of the readStream using those files"? It going against Databricks claims.

Comment: Thanks @Boris I could just have a lower frequency trigger and would achieve the same effect I believe, but then again I'll be slower consuming

Comment: @Boris " It going against Databricks claims." I was told this by databricks solution engineers. Maybe they were wrong, but I've asked them several times about that. can you please refer me to where they claim otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Databrick's delta guarantees

[OPTIMIZE guarantees](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html):

```
Performing OPTIMIZE on a table that is a streaming source does not affect 
any current or future streams that treat this table as a source
```

So it's either a bug in Delta's OPTIMIZE or a bug in your code.
I cannot say anything about OPTIMIZE - it's not an open source.

### Suggestion

Manual ways of [compaction](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/49):
(I am running a more complex version of the following in my project) to try follow. Please note that `dataChange` option is extremely important for using the delta sink as a streaming source.

```py
spark.read \
        .format("delta") \
        .load(root_path) \
        .write \
        .format("delta") \
        .option("dataChange", "false") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .save(root_path)
```

Partition compaction, per https://mungingdata.com/delta-lake/compact-small-files/, with my addition of `dataChange`:

```py
spark.read\
  .format("delta")\
  .load(table)\
  .where(partition)\
  .repartition(numFiles)\
  .write\
  .format("delta")\
  .option("dataChange", "false") \
  .mode("overwrite")\
  .option("replaceWhere", partition)\
  .save(table)
```

#### Note

Please note that working with multiple concurrently writing jobs over S3 is [not supported](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/564). This can be one source of problems.

Comment: I know this line in the docs, but explicitly I was told by two different solution architects from Databricks that this isn't true for streaming order, it won't "break" the stream from running. I currently trying to find a definitive answer on that, and hoped this question would help with this

Comment: Your answer shows (a way I know) to read files and compact them to a smaller number of files - so maybe with a filter on which records I need (only older then week ago perhaps) It might work if I change my code to use two sources, one for running from the start and one for latest data stream. So even if it doesn't answer my question, I would accept it if you provide the missing part - which is filtering just for older data and removing the relevant files from the storage after that

Comment: Let me understand what you suggest. You will be saving all new data into a new landing zone location, so that you can stream from there, AFAIU. 
You can compact the original curated files once in batch. Are you asking how to compact only the newest curated files?

Comment: Not exactly, What I think i can do is filter in there where clause for "older files" (the data there isn't partitioned) and thus, not breaking streaming downstream consumers (hopefully) . What do you think? I wished there was a way to just do this with OPTIMIZE in databricks 

Can you verify that in your project this kind of changes don't break the downstream consumers?